# How can i create a calendar with customization days using Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i'm a reactjs beginner, i want to create a Calendar using ReactJS in range two days, but i want to divide the squares of days two three shifts or `divs` each shift/div can be clickable. Like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5FlA.png).

I Tried [React-Big-Calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar), [Calendar](https://github.com/react-component/calendar), and [React-Calendar](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar) but no one of them can give me what i want, anyone can help me?

Comment: it is more than , one question , it is project !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [React-Component Calendar](http://react-component.github.io/calendar/) and return div in `dateRender`